Запятая в юридически грамотных формулировках
Как правильно написать?

Запретить представителю по закону малолетнего ФИО-1(,) ФИО-2....

Нужна ли запятая, уточняющая ФИО-2 представителя?
Или два ФИО идут рядом и не нужна запятая?

О запятой между представителем и именем представителя спрашиваете?

Запятая не нужна:

Запретить представителю по закону малолетнего Иванова Ивана Ивановича
Иванову Ивану Ивановичу

Это приложение. Количество рядом стоящих ФИО на запятые не влияет, если они являются разными членами предложения
